# WebView doesn't load static page first time

Tags: android, webview

I am using two webViews to display inside two tabs inside a DialogFragment. The odd behaviour I am observing is, initially, first tab opens blank (without any content in webview).

As I press the second tab, it shows the static page correctly and then if I switch back to the first tab, it even shows the first tab static html correctly. I am having hard time figuring out why it doesn't load the first tab initially. Any ideas?

```
package in.co.madhur.dashclockfeedlyextension;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class AboutDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    private WebView aboutWebView, whatsNewView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.about_tab);
        aboutWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_webview);
        whatsNewView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.whatsnew_webview);



        aboutWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        tabHost.setup();

        builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.feedback_button, new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", Consts.MY_EMAIL, null));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.feedback_button));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.rate_button, new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                        + getActivity().getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try
                {
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + getActivity().getPackageName())));
                }

            }
        });

        TabSpec aboutTab = tabHost.newTabSpec(Consts.ABOUT_TAG);
        aboutTab.setIndicator(getString(R.string.action_about));
        aboutTab.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        //aboutTab.setContent(intent);

        TabSpec whatsnewTab = tabHost.newTabSpec(Consts.WHATS_NEW_TAG);
        whatsnewTab.setIndicator(getString(R.string.whatsnew_tab));
        whatsnewTab.setContent(R.id.tab2);

        tabHost.addTab(aboutTab);
        tabHost.addTab(whatsnewTab);



        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
            {
                Log.v(App.TAG, tabId);

            }
        });

        aboutWebView.loadUrl(Consts.ABOUT_URL);
        whatsNewView.loadUrl(Consts.CHANGES_URL);

        return builder.create();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            boolean result = false;

            /* ... */
            // Return false to proceed loading page, true to interrupt loading

            return result;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue.? i am also facing here.

Answer (score 0):

Override and do your loading logic in the `onViewCreated` method after the dialog (and WebView) has been created and initialized.